# How to view server side scripting in extjs

Tags: extjs

I'm working with a long form/survey in extjs which calls a script which then does a lot of checking and processing with the submitted form data.  This is all fine, but my problem is that when I submit the script I really need to see what is going on server side.  Currently I am not seeing anything, as the console debug just returns a error if the response is not success/failure.  How can I get eyes on what my form processing script is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an environment/IDE that supports debugging on the server -- this is not something you can do from the browser (short of returning log info from the server as part of your response).  To give one example, if you are using .NET on the back end, you can use Visual Studio to hook into the server (or run a dev server directly inside VS) that lets you set break points and debug server code, even when called from the browser via JS/Ajax.  How or if this would be possible in your case depends entirely on your back end environment.

Comment: Thanks - My backend is ColdFusion 8.  I'm new to extJS and used to be "spoiled" by CF and being able to get a detailed debug output on the client side, like dumping variables and scopes as the form is being processed. I guess I'll have to see what is possible server side.

Comment: No clue, as I have never touched CF. Good luck.